# select result by IN LIST clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my `Group` table :

```
+------+----------+------------------------+----------------+
|  Id  | IdParent |        DateEdit        |     seeds      |
+------+----------+------------------------+----------------+
| 1000 | NULL     | 2015-01-29 17:37:31.74 | 1001,1002,1003 |
+------+----------+------------------------+----------------+
```

This is `products` table:

```
+----+--------+-------------+---------+-----------+
| Id | IdKala | IdGroupChar | IdGroup |   Matn    |
+----+--------+-------------+---------+-----------+
|  1 |    101 |        1001 |    1001 | Product 1 |
|  2 |    102 |        1001 |    1001 | Product 2 |
|  3 |    103 |        1004 |    1004 | Product 3 |
|  3 |    104 |        1006 |    1006 | Product 4 |
|  3 |    105 |        1003 |    1003 | Product 5 |
+----+--------+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

I need to select all records where IdGroupChar is in seeds

```
select Id, IdKala, IdGroupChar, IdGroup, Matn 
from products 
where (IdGroupChar IN (select seeds 
                       from Groups where id=1000)
```

Since seeds is a field content, it return empty table. If seeds was a list of records, it would return result.
What can I do?

Comment: Is `seeds` really a comma-separated list?  If so, then you really shouldn't be storing data in that format it's incredibly difficult to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
SELECT 
    Id, IdKala, IdGroupChar, IdGroup, Matn 
FROM 
    products 
    INNER JOIN Groups 
      ON Groups.id = 1000
        AND PATINDEX ('%,' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),
                                               products.IdGroupChar)
                                       )) + ',%', ',' + Groups.seeds + ',') <> 0
```

[Here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) you might find documentation about `PATINDEX` function.

The above solution should work only if vaules in `seeds` are always separated by nothing more than a comma `,` sign (no whitespaces).

I hope it helps some way.

Comment: here about PATINDEX (Transact-SQL) :Returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a pattern in a specified expression, or zeros if the pattern is not found, on all valid text and character data types.

Comment: The other comment is that I added an extra column with the same data but of char type to compare by IN, while your way permit me to remove extra column, as declared by MSDN : "on all valid text and character data types"

Answer (score -5):

I taken one variable @SEEDS and put seeds string in this variable. So that we can pass that to split function. You can do something like :

```
DECLARE @SEEDS VARCHAR(MAX) = (select seeds from Groups where id=1000)

select A.Id, A.IdKala, A.IdGroupChar, A.IdGroup, A.Matn 
from products as a 
INNER JOIN FNSPLIT(@SEEDS , ',') AS B ON A.IdGroupChar = B.ITEM
```

You need to split seeds and convert that to rows. To this there is one user defined function called [fnsplit](http://geekswithblogs.net/AngelEyes/archive/2007/04/12/111504.aspx) . You need to add this function in your database.

Comment: Can you explain what is the `FNSPLIT`? Also some words about the first line of code.

Comment: That function is about the slowest of all the possible split functions available. Take a look at this article for a number of better alternatives. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: I should add that just because it is a table valued function does NOT make it faster. It is a multi statement table valued function instead of an inline one and they are generally even slower than a scalar function. Add to that the looping and it is super slow.

Comment: We need to split 4-5 values here i guess. It will not make much difference i guess.

Comment: @SeanLange that is problem of bad database design. If developer use child table instead of comma separated values in single column , there won't require split function even. If you want to suggest best approach then you should make comment regarding database structure rather then split function.

Comment: LOL I wasn't the one who suggested the slowest possible splitter. Yes the best approach would be to not store data in violation of 1NF.

Comment: I don't consider speed related thing when give solution to beginners. By looking at database  design i don't think ahmed have any issue with speed. When we split 5 comma seperate values , can you tell me how much speed difference will be there? I don't think there will be more then 0.001 sec.

Comment: You wasn't one who given ans as well. Instead of giving solution , people likes to do down voting.